# Compile not optimized Libgcc for ARM

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, cortex-m, libgcc

Good morning,

I need to compile libgcc from scratch without deploying the ARM optimized version which is defined in ieee754-sf.s in the ARM back-end.
Does anyone knows how to configure GCC for excluding ieee754-sf.s ( in libgcc/config/arm ) to compile from scratch libgcc, in particular compiling vanilla floating-point soft-fp emulation which is in libgcc/spft-fp ?

Thanks

Comment: do you want a configure option? or you want to modify the toolchain yourself?

Comment: A configuration would be great, but I think that unluckily a change in the toolchain is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know a configure command which does what you want. However if you want to do these modifications, you will need to modify lib1funcs.S to delete the references to the two files. you will need also to modify  the t files (t-elf and t-arm at least) . gcc/config/arm/elf.h sould probably be modified too.

You can take a look at microblaze config directory. it shows a minimalist example

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see if I find something.